# svn copy - problem with directories

Tags: svn, svn-copy

I want to create a tag in my repository. My command is:

```
svn copy trunk tags\1.1
```

I execute this command in the main directory of my local working copy. It however copies whole directory so the files ends up in `tags\1.1\trunk` directory, not in `tags\1.1`. I was trying to add slashes or backslashes after the trunk directory name, but it is the same. How can I copy all files and directories from trunk to tag directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does `tags\1.1` already exist, and you're trying to overwrite it? If so then you'll need to delete it first (and commit the deletion), otherwise svn assumes you want to copy `trunk` **into** the existing tag directory.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

change into the trunk directory then do

```
svn copy ./ ..\tags\1.1
```

Comment: You ment `svn copy ./ ..\tags\1.1`? But anyway +1.

Comment: Indeed
Fixed for future reference.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why that wouldn't work, unless it's an issue with being on the local server.  I use the following command and it works as expected, both with my own svn server and with Google Code's server:

svn copy svn://svn_host/project_name/trunk svn://svn_host/project_name/tags/release-1.0.0 -m "Tagging the 1.0.0 release of the 'Project Name' project."